# Tried to write a test case which checks the tasks array length not to be negative and it has to test by using 'not.toBe' by below code getting error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

### index.js

```js
var tasks=[];

tasks=['task one', 'task two'];

module.exports=tasks;
```

### index.test.js

const tasks=require('./index')

test('not to be less tha zero',()=>{

expect(tasks.length).not.toBeLessThan(0)

})

Comment: Can you elaborate on why not.toBe is the only option, because other methods are designed to solve problems like this one.

Comment: so it is mentioned in the question to use i just updated my code pls check

Comment: I tried your code and the test passed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put semicolon in the end of 3rd line.

```
const tasks=require('./index')
test('not to be less tha zero', () => {
   expect(tasks.length).not.toBeLessThan(0);
})
```